# Git command to show my permissions on a given remote

Tags: git

A colleague can fetch from, but not push to a remote repository. I suspect that he has only read and not write permissions on the remote. There are various ways I can check this but I cannot think of one he can use within git.

Is there a git command to show one's permissions on a given remote repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Git doesn't handle any permission mechanism itself. One of the reason he can not push is he doesn't have the right access on the remote filesystem.

Comment: Thanks - so git will try the write, and fail because he has insufficient permissions on the server, and pass the error back?

Comment: @dumbledad Exactly.

Comment: I will mark it, but I do like to hesitate just-in-case others have interesting answers too.