# git and sourcetree user.name confusion

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a project which I want to use a different `user.name` (`leeyuiwah`), which is different to the global value `leeyuiwah-sl`), to talk to a certain repo in `github.com`.  I have already updated the project's `.git/config` but then my command got this error

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to leeyuiwah/brti.git denied to leeyuiwah-sl.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/leeyuiwah/brti.git/': The 
requested URL returned error: 403
```

I ran this and the settings seem to be right:

```
$ git config --list | grep -E -e "user.*name"
credential.username=leeyuiwah
user.name=leeyuiwah
```

But then I realized I had a config file used by `SourceTree` that stored the wrong name

```
$ find . -type f | xargs grep leeyuiwah-sl
./.git/sourcetreeconfig.json:      "Username": "leeyuiwah-sl",
```

So I think I could just edit that JSON file.  I did that but it did not help.

Now I am stuck.  Any suggestion?

**Update**

More info as per comment:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/leeyuiwah/brti.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/leeyuiwah/brti.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
```

And

```
$ git config --list --show-origin | grep leeyuiwah
file:.git/config        
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/leeyuiwah/brti.git
file:.git/config        credential.username=leeyuiwah
file:.git/config        user.name=leeyuiwah
file:.git/config        user.email=leeyuiwah@gmail.com
```

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: @Christoph -- Thanks for helping me.  See my update on the question.  The output looks normal to me.

Comment: Perhaps a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39142102/5784831)?

Comment: I am not sure.  In my case, git seems to be confused with the two usernames that I have -- `leeyuiwah-sl` vs `leeyuiwah`.  Even I seems to have edited the config file correctly, somehow it still picked up the wrong username.

Comment: But then it should also complain when you use the `git remote show origin` command! What about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787432/5784831)? Perhaps you could share the result of `git config --list --show-origin`? There can be only one valid login (user / password) for a repo.

Comment: @Christoph -- The repo is public.  So as a different user I think I still can read it.  Also, I looked at your other link and ran the command `git config --list --show-origin` suggested there. (The output is added to the question)  Again, the output looks normal to me.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, but this was too long for a comment anyway.
My `git config --list --show-origin` looks like this

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
...
file:"C:\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   user.name=my name
file:"C:\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   user.email=my.name@domain.com
file:"C:\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   credential.helper=manager
...
file:.git/config        branch.master.remote=origin
```

There are 3 different config files. The last entry if from the local repo. As I am working on windows with only one name, there is only one `user.name`, ...
See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) for further details.

If you cannot find different `user.names` in different `config` files in your case, something must be wrong (I guess). In other words I would expect something like

```
file:"C:\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   user.name=my name
...
file:.git/config        user.name=my second name
...
```

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks!  In my case, I seems to have made that only one user.name (`leeyuiwah`) is in all the config files, and my `git config --list --show-origin` has confirmed that, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: @leeyuiwah But then it is obvious, that "Permission to leeyuiwah/brti.git denied to leeyuiwah-sl."! There is only leeyuiwah.

Comment: I am confused now.  My remote repo is created by `leeyuiwah` and I want to push my local content to that remote, also using `leeyuiwah`.  I don't understand where git picks up `leeyuiwah-sl` in this process.  The only file under that directory that still has the string `leeyuuiwah-sl` is `.git/sourcetreeconfig.json`, but even if I removed this file, git still picked up the wrong user.name `leeyuiwah-sl`

Comment: You're confusing me ;-) Please go through the remotes, the users what you have and what you expect - step by step.

Comment: Would this be a confusion due to `ssh-agent`?  I may have set up that for `leeyuiwah-sl` (the user.name that should NOT be used).  How do I check?

Comment: Perhaps start with a new `clone` and document the process of setting up the origin...